# How To Access OpenVPN client from internal lan

Tags: networking, openvpn, subnet

We have just recently implemented openvpn and have run into an issue.

We are trying to attach our disaster recovery server to the network through openvpn.  The internal lan ip range is 192.168.10.0 and the static IP being assigned to the disaster recovery server through openvpn is 6.6.6.1.  The disaster recovery server has no problem accessing any of the clients/servers on the lan but the internal clients can't reach the disaster recovery server.

I see that the IP address is registered in DNS as soon as the client connects and when trying to ping it using its FQDN it resolves just fine.  It just can't access the actual machine.

I am not a networking expert by any means so I am at a complete loss as to what to do here.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated and if you need me to provide any further information please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out the answer myself thankfully.  I had to set up a static route in my firewall and use the OpenVPN server IP as the gateway ip.  This opened everything up.

Thanks.